# JS Prototype Multi-layer Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Why doesn't this work?

```
function Component(actor) {
    this.actor = actor;
    //...
}

Component.prototype.run = function() {
    console.log("Inheritance Error: Component.run()");
};



function Intersection(actor) {
    if (actor !== undefined) {
        Component.call(this, actor);
        ...
    }
}
Intersection.prototype = new Component();

Intersection.prototype.run = function() {
    //...
};



function FloorIntersection(actor, list) {
    Intersection.call(this, actor);
    ...
}
FloorIntersection.prototype = new Intersection();



var fi = new FloorIntersection(actor, list);
fi.run();
```

It gives me 'undefined is not a function' when I try calling: fi.run(). However if I do

```
var i = new Intersection(actor);
i.run();
```

Then it works.

It's unbelievably frustrating because I have the exact same structure elsewhere (ZachCharacterView -> Sprite -> Component) and it works just fine.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works.

Comment: You're right it does..when it is all in the same document. I know this is moving into a separate issue but I have PHP loading all my js files. I'm wondering now that I have 50+ js files if there is an issue with loading all of them and js throwing errors because its looking for functions that have not yet been loaded? Should I dump all my js documents into one large file?

Comment: It's ok. You can do that. The point is you need to merge them in a correct order.